# Flutter touch events passing through Drawer Element to underlying UIKitView with embedded WKWebView

Tags: ios, flutter, wkwebview, webview-flutter

I've got a Plugin which uses a UIKitView which contains a WKWebView on iOS and a AndroidView with WebView on Android. The Android solution is working as expected, but I've got two problems on iOS. First, some contents of the web-view, e.g. HTML content, is overlaying the AppBar and second, i can click right through a Drawer element which triggers some click events of my HTML page. I've been able to "solve" the first problem by putting the plugin view into a ClipRect.

Any ideas what causes this behaviour and how to solve it, especially the second one?

Comment: Even I am passing through the second issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I have filed an issue with flutter but for now, I did but it is just a workaround not a proper fix with javaScript channel to enabled/disabled clicked events on drawer open/close events respectively. I know this is only possible when you have access to the webpage source.

Comment: you can track this issue here:  http://gestyy.com/erZEyQ